# Question about cycle notation of permutations.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The following paragraph of Contemporary Abstract Algebra I don't understand the words underlined by red:

[image]

.

.

The word fix I understand it in the following underlined by red:

.

.

[image]

Comment: $\alpha$ fixes $x$ means $\alpha(x) = x$. $(24)$ is the permuation that exchanges $2$ and $4$ and fixes everything else. It is hard to help much more with the proof you quote, because you haven't quoted the statement of the theorem being proved.

Comment: @RobArthan  The theorem I understand it....but my problem why he wrote  for example 
(3) and (12) both fix 4.  I mean why he specifies 4 .

Comment: @RobArthan and thank you for your trying to clarify my problem.

Comment: Because $4$ is where you have got to in the computation of $(\alpha\beta)(1)$  when you have just done $(45)$ while working through the cyclic permutations right-to-left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These all mean the same thing:

- $\sigma(x) = x$
- $\sigma$ fixes $x$
- $x$ is a fixed point of $\sigma$
- $x$ is fixed by $\sigma$

The verb "to fix" is used in the sense of "to keep in place".

Comment: Thank you for your answer....but my question   why he wrote for example (3) and (12) both fix 4. I mean why he specifies 4?
and another example he wrote (24) fixes 1

Comment: This point confused me ....but every thing else is clear.

Comment: He’s computing the image of $1$ under $\alpha\beta$. Start applying the pieces: first (24), then (153), then (45), then (3), then (12). He’s observing that their effects are: (24) fixes 1; then (153) sends 1 to 5; then (45) sends 5 to 4; then (3) fixes 4; then (12) fixes 4. You apply the next piece to the previous result at each step. All together, you have computed that $\alpha\beta$ has sent 1 to 4. And so on. Next, you would see what happens to 4, so you’re building $1\to 4\to \cdots$. Understand?

Comment: Ok thank you for your explanation ...all respect to you.

Comment: Final question please Can I say he mean (24) as ( (24) (1) (3) (5) ) so it fixes one?

Comment: The cycle (24) fixes every element not in the cycle; specifically, it fixes 1, 3, and 5. That’s implicit in the notation. So, yes, (24)=(24)(1)(3)(5). I wouldn’t write it that way though—why add in the part that doesn’t move?